# How to reload a previous page when segue back

Tags: ios, swift

I use this line of code in my iOS app

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
```

It takes the user back the login page, but it does not reload the login with all the most recent data.

It will not run this code again:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
 }
```

How do I make the segue cause the viewDidLoad again?

Comment: It's not supposed to run "ViewDidLoad" again, the view is already loaded. But it will run ViewWillAppear as Dharmesh said below, you need to reconfigure to handle events like this. This is the correct flow for view controllers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `viewWillAppear` method for that.

Comment: Yes move the code that you use to reload into `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a web call from `viewDidLoad()`. So to update your viewController add your web request method in `viewWillAppear()`.

Note:  `viewDidLoad` gets called only when the view controller loads which happen once. However `viewWillAppear` gets called before it appears which will often happen if you're hopping back and forth between views.